# show input errors of active form in an alert box yii2

Tags: php, jquery, validation, yii2

I have a form in my web app which written in php language under yii2 framework.
now i have designed my own form with custom css and i don't want to show errors under each input.
I have canceled error showing with `fieldconfig` in yii2 form.
But it is a bug for a system that doesn't show error of inputs to the users.
I want to show errors in another div or in an alert box.
how should i do this?

here is my form

```
<?php
                $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'enableClientValidation' => true,
                    fieldConfig' => ['template' => "{label}\n{input}"]
                    ])
                ?>

                <?= $form->field($regModel, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'txtbox_name', 'placeholder' => 'نام'])->label('') ?>

                <?= $form->field($regModel, 'family')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'txtbox_name', 'placeholder' => 'نام خانوادگی'])->label('') ?>

                <?= $form->field($regModel, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'txtboxpass', 'placeholder' => 'پست الکترونیک'])->label('') ?>

                <?= $form->field($regModel, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'txtboxpass', 'placeholder' => 'رمز عبور'])->label('') ?>

                <?= $form->field($regModel, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'txtboxpass', 'placeholder' => 'رمز عبور'])->label('') ?>

                <?= $form->field($regModel, 'grade_id')->dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Grade::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'), ['prompt' => 'انتخاب مقطع', 'class' => 'drglist'])->label(''); ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('ثبت نام', ['class' => 'btn_sabt', 'id' => 'reg']) ?>
                </div>        
                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

please help me it is so necessary/
thank you

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633853/errors-on-submit-in-a-popup-box

Comment: I checked if out my friend @Farshid it is for yii 1 as I mentioned .  i want yii 2.

Comment: what would the value of `fieldConfig['template']` (in this case `"{label}\n{input}"`) generally be used for? also (I think) typo: `fieldConfig'` should be `'fieldConfig'`

Comment: fieldConfig is used for hide the error messages. but i want to show errors in another dive @Scaramouche

Comment: you want the runtime client validation that triggers on blur to be replaced with the alerts or when you submit the form? and by alert you mean any fancy alert?

Comment: You are missing a single quote by the way.

Comment: yes @MuhammadOmerAslam buddy.

Comment: in which line? @JairusMartin

Comment: Could be a paste error, see line for: fieldConfig' .

Comment: Have you seen my updated notes? Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **For the error summary:**

```
<?= $form->errorSummary($regModel) ?>
```

### **To hide the help-block**

1. Option#1: Rather than using the activeform, try the HTML helper class:

   ```
   use yii\helper\Html;

   <?= Html::input('text', 'username', $user->name, ['class' => $username]) ?>
   ```
2. Option#2: You can try at the activeField level:

   ```
   // With 'default' layout you would use 'template' to size a specific field:
   echo $form->field($model, 'demo', [
       'template' => '{label} 
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-4">{input}{error}{hint}</div>
           </div>'
   ]);
   ```
3. Option#3: Set at the activeForm level, verify elements using the inspect debug tool in Chrome or Mozilla:

   ```
   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
       'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
       'fieldConfig' => [
           'template' => "{label}\n{input}\n{hint}",
           //'errorOptions' => ['class' => 'help-block'],
       ],
   ]); ?>
   ```

Reference:

- https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-html
- https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.2/yii-bootstrap-activefield

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`Html::errorSummary()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#errorSummary()-detail) to display errors summary in any place:

```
<?= Html::errorSummary($regModel) ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it did not work`? How do you use it? Did `$regModel->getErrors()` returns anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the errors using 'afterValidate';

Put this code at the end of the view;

'#w0' is the form id element (you can get it using inspect from your browser);

```
$script = <<< JS
$('#w0').on('afterValidate', function (event, messages, errorAttributes) {
        //console.log('afterValidate');
        if (errorAttributes.length) {
            //alert('Verifique os errors!'); 
        }
        $.each(messages, function(index, element) {
           if(element.length > 0) {
               console.log(element);
               alert(element);
           }
       });
  });
  JS;
  $this->registerJs($script);
```